# Session using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

How to manage session without page refresh?

Description :  I have a model popup on First.aspx page , open Second.aspx page in popup using iframe when click on button from First.aspx 
I want to get value from `Second.aspx` (server side) as `session["Value"]` and show on `First.aspx` page when popup close without reload the  `First.aspx`  is this possible??

i tried like this - 
but this session value show after reload the  First.aspx

.cs code (First.aspx)

```
 Session["ComplaintValue"] = hfPresentComplaint.Value.Replace("'", "''");
```

Javascript code ()

```
<script>
  function closepopupsession() {
    debugger;
    var a = ' <%=Session["ComplaintValue"]%>'
    if (a != null) {
      var hidnvalComplaint = document.getElementById("hidnvalueComplaint").value
      console.log(replaced);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not clear! Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: My suggestion is to use websocket technology and your program can works anything without refresh. Close sesion on server side and just notify client with last signal. On client make proper msg box for losing connection or session expired....

Comment: @RameshRajendran create session from first page(using iframe) and use that second page using javascript (wiout reload second page)

Comment: Note that that `<%=Session["ComplaintValue"]%>` is executed server side, *before* that javascript block is sent to the browser. That browser sees only a string value (with extra space, and which will never be null) and doesn't know about any "session".

Answer (score 0):

there is different tricks to do this,but in my case im using Ajax to call separate page every 1sec which i have my sessions there,and an empty div in the index page,like below :

```
        function RefreshSessions()
        {
          var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
          req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
             if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
             {
              document.getElementById('EmptyDiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
             }
        }
            req.open('GET', 'update_sessions.php', true);
            req.send();
        }
            setInterval(function(){RefreshSessions()}, 1000);
```

Hope it will help.